# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Well, My issue is different.. I created a modal form like this:

[Modal Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS4q2.png)

There is no issue at all and my data can be edited easily:

[Updates with no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XfMj.png)

Now, I started to replace the text area with Vue2-editor plugin and the resulting design is like the following:

[Vue-text-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyQEC.png)

I tried to modify the texts and save:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKyUY.png)

Here is my updating mechanism:

```
updateProduct() {
        // Update function has issues so I have to apply this work-around
        this.$firestore.products.doc(this.product['.key']).set(this.product).then(() => {
          this.$firestore.products.doc(this.activeItem).delete()}).then(()=>{
            this.$refs.edit.hide()
              toast.fire({
                  type: 'success',
                  title: 'Updated successfully'
              });
          });
      },
```

Well, the firebase update function does not work at all. I have researched this, but in vain - this is the only working workaround for it.

Now I need to figure out what's wrong with that text editor.

Comment: Here is my recorded live action video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-etDOq9-7w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
this.$firestore.products.doc(this.product['.key'])
```

I don't know what the contents of `this.product['.key']` is, but it's almost certainly not going to give you the name of a collection and the name of a document together.  The only way you can reference a document is through a collection.  Documents don't exist outside of collection.  That's why the number of path segments in the string you pass to doc() must be even.  It should be of the form "collection/document".

You will have to identify the collection you're writing to, and reference the path of the document using it.